# Multi window free form mode: Restrict vertical or horizontal resizing capacity o a window

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, multi-window, android-task

I am trying to make a launcher application that launches some predefined set of apps in the multi-window Free form mode, and I have made some progress in doing that so far.
However I am working on a new use case where I need to restrict the resizing capacity of a newly launched window to either horizontal/vertical direction but not in both.

Here is what it looks like.
[image]

Presently both the activity windows can be freely expanded/shrunk in both horizontal/vertical directions. However I want to restrict to any one of them. I cannot find any means to do this yet, and would really appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not aware that this is an available option.

Comment: I did a sort of work around not sure if it is very efficient. I did set a RestrictedCaptionAreaListener [link] (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.OnRestrictedCaptionAreaChangedListener# ) and in the listener function I am always setting the window height to a hard-coded value by:   getWindow().setAttributes()